# perl equivalent of my regular expression to handle a multi line search

Tags: regex, linux, perl, unix, awk

am new to regular expressions and i cant handle a regex search using grep..
so thought of trying perl

can you give a perl equivalent to the regex

```
^\s*\*\s*\[ \][^\*]+?(\w*\:[^\*]+\d$)|([^\*]+[.]com[.]au$)
```

i want to execute it on a file in linux..
a multiline search... can anyone help me out?

even an awk command that can handle my operation would do..

and am already working on this at the following links

[Scope of grep with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014032/scope-of-grep-with-regular-expressions/11014110#11014110)

[a regular expression to grep specific paragraphs of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009386/a-regular-expression-to-grep-specific-paragraphs-of-a-file/11010001#11010001)

when i use the expression as it is,
it gives me: `syntax error near "^"`

Comment: Ehm just surround expression with /

Comment: It's difficult to newer without knowing what you're trying to match against. It looks like syntactically valid expression and so it should run. Perhaps if you could enhance your question with examples of what you get versus what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to work it out using 
PCREGREP utility

```
pcregrep -M '(^\s*\*\s*\[ \][^\*]+?(\w*\:[^\*]+\d$)|([^\*]+[.]com[.]au$))' file1
```

that did it :)
thanks @Damian @jack

Answer (score 1):

You're looking how to use the above regex with perl from commandline (one-liner)? try:

```
perl -nle 'print if /regex_here/' < file
```

e.g.

```
perl -nle 'print if /bin/' < /etc/passwd
```

will print out all lines with "bin", and

```
perl -nle 'print if /^\s*\*\s*\[ \][^\*]+?(\w*\:[^\*]+\d$)|([^\*]+[.]com[.]au$)/' < file
```

should do what you want.